# Invoke a function before the action hook

Tags: actions

I want to invoke a function before a special action. I want to validate the input of a custom metabox (or custom field) before the changes are saved. If the input value is invalid, then a stop save action with a message should be invoked. If the input fiels is valid, input value should be saved to DB.

```
add_action('save_change','my_function');
function my_function(){
    if(validate($input){
        //do core action 
    }else{
        //show message and stop action, don't save other field
    }
}
```

Please advise for me how to implement this problem.

Answer (score 0):

For this specific problem you can use [Rilwis metabox plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/meta-box/), where you can define custom metabox along with the validation.

Comment: thank you. But I don't want use plugin, can you guide me how code to resolve this problem?